# DataTable makeEditable is not working (not a function), are my JS scripts compatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I have had a large list of issues with trying to make my datatable editable, so I would like to check if my scripts are compatible.

```
    <div th:replace="fragments/partial :: partialJs"></div>
<div th:replace="fragments/withEasy :: js"></div>


<script type="text/javascript"
    src="../../resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
    th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js}"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="../../resources/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.editable.js"
    th:src="@{/resources/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.editable.js}"></script> // ver 2.3.3.

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="../../resources/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"
    th:src="@{/resources/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js}"></script> //ver 1.10.0

        <script type="text/javascript"
    src="../../resources/js/jquery.jeditable.js"
    th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery.jeditable.js}"></script>
    // Version 1.7.3


    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="../../resources/js/jquery.validate.min.js"
    th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery.validate.min.js}"></script> //v1.13.1
```

Comment: You should add a `thymeleaf` tag to your question and include that in your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading jQuery twice, second time from `cdn.datatables.net`. Use the link without jQuery embedded, i.e. `https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js`

Also you're loading DataTables script twice, first from `cdn.datatables.net` and then locally from `../../resources/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js`. Remove `../../resources/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js`,

Aslo `jquery.jeditable.js` needs to be loaded before `jquery.dataTables.editable.js`.